# UIPageViewControllerDataSource - segueForUnwindingToViewController not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have a UIViewController that is set up as a UIPageViewControllerDataSource named MainPVC.swift.  It is my entry point on my Storyboard.  In it, I am instantiating another UIViewController named TrackerVC which is set up in my Storyboard - but not connected to MainPVC by segue.

**Instantiating TrackerVC:**

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TrackerVC {
    let childViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("trackerVC") as TrackerVC
    childViewController.screenIndex = index
    return childViewController
}
```

I have another UIViewController named NotesVC.  When I push a button on TrackerVC, I use a custom UIStoryBoardSegue to display NotesVC.  On NotesVC, I have another button that I want to return to TrackerVC using another custom UIStoryboardSegue via Unwind.

**Cancel button tapped in NotesVC:**

```
@IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindFromNotesSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

Now to my issue -

When I push the button on TrackerVC, the custom UIStoryboardSegue works great and displays NotesVC as expected.  However, when I tap the button on NotesVC, the custom UIStoryboardSegue is ignored and the generic segue that slides the view down is being used.

I have traced the issue down to segueForUnwindingToViewController not being called in TrackerVC.  I have all of my connections set up properly in my Storyboard and all of the required methods (the method unwind uses).

I have also tried creating a 3rd UIViewController and displaying it using the custom UIStoryboardSegues along with Unwind and calling it from NotesVC and everything works fine.  segueForUnwindingToViewController is being called on NotesVC as expected.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Do you have `NavigationController` attached?  You may need to subclass the `NavigationController` and add the `segueForUnwindingToViewController` there. It's what solved the similar problem I was having.